# Regex - replace wrappers around strings

Tags: regex, string, search, replace, wrapper

What would be a regex expression that could turn this:

```
{{ Form::label('events', 'Events') }}
```

Into this:

```
<label for="events">Events</label>
```

I need the strings "events" and "Events" to remain in tact.

Comment: Don't do this using regexp unless you like the idea of prematurely gray hair.

Comment: Why not? The provided solutions work great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
s/.*::(.*?)\('(.*?)',\s'(.*?)'.*/<$1 for="$2">$3</$1>/
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/aF2iA5/1)

Answer (score 1):

This would also work for your sample, this is formatted with sed:

```
sed -E "s#[^']+'([^']+)', '([^']+)'.*#<label for=\"\1\">\2</label>#"
```

If you want it in two pieces:

```
s#[^']+'([^']+)', '([^']+)'.*
<label for=\"\1\">\2</label>
```

Comment: You hard-coded `label`. Why not capture and re-use?

Comment: Ha... I didn't notice that because the requestor focused on "events" and "Events".